# MySQl, Can not insert data into the table from Java

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner of MySQL and I am using Java to insert 6 items into database table, in here it called "registration" table, I copied/pasted the insert SQL statement from phpMyAdmin, but when running Java program, it always SQL exception happened. I checked database, no new record was added. My db access statement and exception are as below,

```
QUERY:  INSERT INTO `student`.`registration` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `HomeAdd`,   `PhoneNumber`, `SSN`, `BirthDate`) VALUES ('Don', 'Williaams', '560 Young St', '900-899-6756', '112-123-7637', '12-09-1980')

java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
```

In the Java, I wrote code like following

```
String query = "INSERT INTO `student`.`registration` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `HomeAdd`, `PhoneNumber`, `SSN`, `BirthDate`) VALUES ('" + "Don', 'Williaams', '560 Young St', '900-899-6756', '112-123-7637', '12-09-1980"+"')";

rs2 = st2.executeQuery(query);
```

I switched insert statement in Java as following

```
String query = "INSERT INTO `student`.`registration` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `HomeAdd`, `PhoneNumber`, `SSN`, `BirthDate`) VALUES ('Don', 'Williaams', '560 Young St', '900-899-6756', '112-123-7637', '12-09-1980')";
```

The Exception is still happened and is same as before

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
```

Is there any wrong with my query statement?
Thanks for help in advance

Susan

Comment: u r missing a close bracket

Comment: Let us know the exact error its complaining??

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `)`. You also need to use `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery`. Try the following:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO `student`.`registration` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `HomeAdd`, `PhoneNumber`, `SSN`, `BirthDate`) VALUES ('" + "Don', 'Williaams', '560 Young St', '900-899-6756', '112-123-7637', '12-09-1980"+"')";

rs2 = st2.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: Thank you Dhaou, I just added ")" at the end of insert statement, but exception is same

Comment: Dear Dhaou, yes you are right, after using executeUpdate, I can insert the data into the table, already no exception, you are a genious! Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following query,and i think in sql date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`   so change it too(here i am expecting you have specified the data type `date` rather than `varchar` while creating your table)

```
String query = "INSERT INTO student.registration (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `HomeAdd`, `PhoneNumber`, `SSN`, `BirthDate`) VALUES ('" + "Don', 'Williaams', '560 Young St', '900-899-6756', '112-123-7637', '1980-09-12"+"')";

rs2 = st2.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: Yes, I switch to executeUpdate, it is work and no more exception, thank you very much for kind help, Susan

Answer (score 0):

`executeQuery` for `Select` statement. You can't run an insert statement with `executeQuery`. Use `executeUpdate` instead. It should solve the issue.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO `student`.`registration` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `HomeAdd`, `PhoneNumber`, `SSN`, `BirthDate`) VALUES ('" + "Don', 'Williaams', '560 Young St', '900-899-6756', '112-123-7637', '12-09-1980"+"')";

rs2 = st2.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, ricky2527 for your kind help, executeUpdate is good choice, I have resolved the issue